# Changing The Format Of Json File Using String Maniputlation

Tags: json, python-3.x, replace, nlp, nvidia-jetson

I have a JSON file that looks something like this:

```
"{""audio_filepath"": ""/content/drive/MyDrive/nemo_commonvoice/wav_files/wav_train/sample-000001.wav"", ""duration"": 2.232, ""text"": ""it took her a while to get used to it""}"
```

I want the extra `"` to be removed from each of the lines so that my output looks something like this: - **The original JSON format**

```
{"audio_filepath": "/content/drive/MyDrive/nemo_commonvoice/wav_files/wav_train/sample-000001.wav", "duration": 2.232, "text": "it took her a while to get used to it"}
```

I require a function that can do the string manipulation for me or at least some hint on how to fix it.

For my function which parses the entire JSON file is:

```
def create_manifest(data: List[tuple], output_name: str, manifest_path: str):

"Takes in the data, which is a tsv file and parses its columns to create a JSON file"

    output_file = Path(manifest_path)/output_name
    output_file.parent.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)

    with output_file.open(mode='w') as f:
        for wav_path,duration,text in tqdm(data,total=len(data)):
            f.write(
                json.dumps({
                    'audio_filepath': wav_path,
                    "duration": duration,
                    'text': text
                }) + '\n'
            )
```

Any help will be beneficial.

Comment: Can you copy paste your json in a visual studio or notepad(whatever suits) and find and replace the occurrence of : ""/ with : "/

Comment: Thanks, I actually that only , its much more easy that way